# What's wrong with order function in data frame?

Tags: r

```
DF <- data.frame(CpGId, tframe$t, tframe$p, q)
dimnames(DF)[[2]] <- c("CpGId", "t_value", "p_value", "q_value")
DFhyper <- DF[with(DF, q_value < 0.05 & t_value> 0), ]
DFhyper <- data.frame(DFhyper, row.names = NULL)
DFhyper <- DFhyper [order(p_value), ]
```

Until fourth line of code, things work fine but then why R gives an error stating `p_value object not found`?

Comment: How about this ? `DFhyper <- DFhyper [order(DFhyper$p_value), ]`

Comment: @Sotos Yeah, that works, but why we have to mention DFhyper again, when we have already mentioned it outside of order function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R executes the bracketed expression first, without paying any attention to how it is going to be used.  When you type

```
DFhyper[order(p_value),]
```

R will look for `p_value` in the current scope (probably the global scope), however, as this is bound into the dataframe, it will not be able to find it.  You need to do something to tell it where this is located.

Either

```
DFhyper[order(DFhyper$p_value),]
```

or

```
DFhyper[with(DFhyper,order(p_value)),]
```

(or nearly equivalent, `with(DFhyper,DFHyper[order(p_value),])`) will work.  The first command tells R specifically that you are referencing the column in the data frame, and the second tells R to look in the dataframe for the variable if it can't find it in scope.

Finally, you can just bind the dataframe into the scope as well, executing

```
attach(DFhyper)
DFhyper[order(p_value),]
```

The attach command adds the dataframe columns to the current scope.  It can be useful for when you have many operations on the dataframe columns, but don't want to keep referencing it.  You can then *detach* it with `detach(DFhyper)` when you are done.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Matthew! But what really is the current scope? Isn't it DFhyper?

Comment: @vib321 No, unless you have done something to change the scope, it would currently be the global scope.  The reference to DFhyper outside the brackets has no influence on what occurs inside.  R executes the braketed expression first, without paying any attention to what you are going to do with it (index into a dataframe), so it doesn't even see that dataframe when it evaluates the bracket.  This way you could use any variable for that ordering even if it wasn't part of the dataframe - even a global variable with the same name as the dataframe column.

Comment: Exactly! Now, I get it why my global P values could also be used in the brackets, and no error was shown! Thanks Matthew

Answer (score 2):

It needs to be

```
DFhyper <- DFhyper [order(Dfhyper$p_value), ]
```

Comment: I thought that way but my bad I didn't implemented it to check. Yeah it works fine. But we have already used DFhyper outside the order function for reference, why we use it again?